# Need help assigning values to array C# (noob)

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to write a method that will assign each day of the year a value for rainfall after checking if it rain at all.

So I want my `days` array to contain 365 random numbers below 28, 3/4 of them being 0.

note: I have a global random variable

```
static void Generate() 
{
    int[] days = new int[365];

    int going_to_rain = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++) 
    {
        going_to_rain = randomValue.Next(3);
        if (going_to_rain == 1) 
        {
            days[i] = randomValue.Next(1, 28);
        } 
        else 
        {
            days[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(days);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? To print the values correctly, just write  `Console.WriteLine(days[i]);` before exiting the for loop.

Comment: Do you want exactly 3/4, _i.e._ 273 elements 0? or do you want a 3/4 _probability_ of elements being 0? there's a difference and right now you're going for the latter.

Comment: very helpful comment, claudiu.

Comment: i want 3/4 probability of being 0

Comment: Then your code's output should be fine after changing it per Claudiu's comment.

Comment: just checked it with Console.WriteLine(days[i]);, how embarrassing I posted a question about working code haha

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array that its first 274 cells are 0, and the others are random.

Afterward you shuffle this array randomally:

```
int[] days = new int[365];
int i = 0;
for(i = 0;i < 274;++i)
{
   days[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 275;i < 365; ++i)
{
   days[i] = randomValue.Next(1,28);
}

//Shuffle
for (i = 0; i < 365; ++i)
{
   int randVal = randomValue.Next(364);
   int tmp = day[randVal];
   day[randVal] = day[i];
   day[i] = tmp;
}
```